# Plot points in google map with python with google api

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps-api-3, bokeh, geospatial

I'm trying to plot some points on a map, and when searching on the internet, I found [this][1] tutorial with Google Maps and Bokeh library. The problem is that, after doing all the steps to get a key in google api, to set the environment variable, when I try to plot, it says that google maps weren't able to load.
Since I don't have much time, and I really need to plot some data (UTM coordinates, that I Intend to transform to latitude and longitude with pyproj), I was wondering if someone knows, another library, with examples, easy to work,  with where I could plot my data (is a pandas dataframe with East, Northing, Elevation).

This is the code from the example I'm trying to reproduce:

```
import os
ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('ACCESS_KEY_ID')
api_key = os.environ['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
df = pd.read_csv('dvf_gex.csv')
lat, lon = 46.2437, 6.0251
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions
bokeh_width=500
bokeh_height=500
def plot(lat, lng, zoom=10, map_type='roadmap'):
    gmap_options = GMapOptions(lat=lat, lng=lng, 
                               map_type=map_type, zoom=zoom)
    p = gmap(api_key, gmap_options, title='Pays de Gex', 
             width=bokeh_width, height=bokeh_height)
    show(p)
    return p
```

this is the error I got:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The error I get on my browser console is:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I have activated the Maps Embed API, is that enough? should I have another API activated?
[1]: https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/show-data-google-map-python/#commento-login-box-container
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxoXS.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjqc2.png

Answer (score 0):

I guess Google has retired the GMap version that Bokeh 2.4.2 specifies by default? That is pretty annoying and user-unfriendly of them. However, you can specify any API version to use by passing it to `gmap`, e.g.

```py
gmap(api_key, api_version="3.47", ...)
```

Comment: I have also made an issue about potentially using the recent "update channels" as the default version for Bokeh: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/12112